# Best way to store password protected assets for use on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

i have a rails application on heroku and would like to store some assets on amazon. What i would like to achieve is that only the heroku app is allowed to access some of the assets. For example some PDF documents on amazon.
I assume i have to use amazon cloudfront and the aws SDK on heroku?

How to do this exactly and is this possible? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think carrierwave with fog will do what you need. https://github.com/fog/fog  (storage = Fog::Storage.new(:provider => 'AWS', :aws_access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID, :aws_secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

Comment: thanks @cristian but do in need carrierwave when i only want to download files ?

Comment: i think not, fog should do what you want without carrierwave.